# C program treats an if statement as false when it is in fact true

Tags: if-statement

The following is a portion of code that I am writing for a homework assignment in my EEL4834 class.  This is just for practice and not for a grade.

My problem is that the compiler is treating my if statement as false when it is true.  I believe it to be true because I test the statement by printing the value of my variable in the else statement, and the value that is printed for my variable is the value that I am asking in the if statement.

The code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{  
    char a, b, c, d, box;
    float box1;

    printf("\nPlease enter the box type as a, b, c, or d:  ");
    scanf("\n%c", &box);

    if (box == a){  
        box1 = .05;
        printf("%f", box1);
        }
    else{
        printf("\n%c\n", box);
        }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The output looks something like this...

```
Please enter a box type as a, b, c, or d: a

a
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The output is telling me that box is in fact a, but if box is a then why isn't the compiler treating the if statement as true?  I omitted the if statements that include options for b, c, or d for simplicity.

I apologize if this is something stupid.  I tried to use the search engine and anything relevant seemed much more complex that my issue.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Always define your variables, even with null/0. `char a = 'a', b = 'b', c = 'c', d = 'd', box = 0;    float box1 = 0;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (box == a){
```

compares the variable `box` against the variable `a` (which is undefined).

You should probably compare it against the character:

```
if (box == 'a') {
```

That also means you can get rid of the variables `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`, since they're not used for anything:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char box;
    float box1;

    printf("\nPlease enter the box type as a, b, c, or d:  ");
    scanf("\n%c", &box);

    if (box == 'a') {
        box1 = .05;
        printf ("%f", box1);
    } else {
        printf("\n%c\n", box);
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing against the variable named `a`, and not the literal character `'a'`.

To understand what I mean, see a tutorial like [this one](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_constants.htm)